# How to call startactivityforresult from a non-activity class to get the resuts

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to call `startActivityForResult()` from a non-activity class to get the results?

Scenario is something like this:

I have a class `NonActivity` (it doesn't derive from Activity as its not a UI).
This class will have bunch of functions(steps basically) to run.
One of the steps requires to show UI(Activity) and then get the result (user enter something).
Then been able to use that data in next following steps.

How can this be achieved without deriving from activity class as I don't have UI component?
Also since I don't want to derive from activity class that means I cannot override `OnActivityResult()`. Where results actually come from?

Answer (score 23):

`startActivityForResult()` is only available from real on-screen activities, since it is a method in, well, Activity. Please redesign your application so that the user interface is driven from activities.

On the other hand, if your non Activity class is initialized and used from an onscreen Activity, you could pass that instance of the Activity to your class as a parameter in the constructor and use it to launch other Activities.

Be careful though. Using this method increases the risk of a memory leak, as the external class (Utils in my example) might keep a reference to the Activity even after its gone.

If all you want to do is access data, then you could try writing it to SharedPreferences or a Database or some files and then using the application context (passed in via a constructor again) to read it. This reduces the risk of a memory leak. Something like:

```
MyApiClass myApiClass = new MyApiClass(getApplicationContext());
```

**EXAMPLE CODE**

Main Activity:

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Utils util = new Utils(this);
        util.startTest();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

}
```

Utils class (which launches for result):

```
public class Utils {

    Activity activity;

    public Utils(Activity ac) {
        activity = ac;
    }

    public void startTest() {
        Intent i = new Intent(activity, Test.class);
        activity.startActivityForResult(i, 1);

    }

}
```

Test Activity:

```
public class Test extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        this.finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: startActivityForResult method not work from non Activity class becuase we can only override onActivityresult in Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I just tried it and it works fine. Let me post some example code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Bascially reason for using Non-Activity class is that I want to encapsulate the whole process into a class(API) then anyone who wants to use this class can call its API. This API executes series of steps and some of them involves taking data from user in form of activity. Even if we forget about startActivityForResult all I want is data from a activity in the non activity class is this scenario not a valid one in android?

Comment: If all you want is data, then you could try writing it to SharedPreferences or a Database or some files and then using the application context (passed in via a constructor again) to read it. This reduces the risk of a memory leak.

Comment: @RaghavSood : yes i agree with u , we must override onActivityResult in Activity instead of non activity class as OP asking

Comment: You are still essentially calling it from an activity in this example

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Guess we're on the same page then :P I misunderstood you the first time. Sorry

Comment: @codeMagic Yes of course. There is no way to call it without any Activity at all. This method just allows the OP to have the code pre written, and the person using his API just has to pass in an Activity reference for it to work, instead of writing the code themselves to do whatever task

Comment: Yes, I figured that's what you meant but threw in my 2 cents. +1 for clarity :)

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. Basically I want to develop a library which perform certain task which involves running certain series of steps.

one of the steps can be involve starting an activity(UI to get input) and use that data to finish that step.

 

So is this bad design that a library starting an activity.. from android perspective

From scenario perspective we should be able to do that right?

Answer (score 7):

StartActivityForResult from a class using a fragment with no visible GUI.  You might find something like this in a utility class.

see runGetUserAccount below.  It creates its own fragment and executes a startActivityForResult.  Then it has it's own onActivityResult.

```
public class MyGooglePlay {

    private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 31502;
    private ActionBarActivity activity;
    private FragmentManager fragManager;

    public MyGooglePlay(ActionBarActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.fragManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }


     /**
     * Starts an activity in Google Play Services so the user can pick an
     * account
     */
    private String mEmail = "";
    static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT = 1000;    
    public void runGetUserAccount() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmail)) {
            // run this code in gui less fragment so we can pickup the 
            // on activity result from inside the mygoogleplay class.
            Fragment f = new Fragment() {
                @Override
                public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
                    super.onAttach(activity);
                    String[] accountTypes = new String[] { "com.google" };
                    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null,
                            null, accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                        Intent data) {
                    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
                        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            set_Email(data
                                    .getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME));
                            // getUsername();
                        }
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }

                //this is to verify the fragment has been removed.
                //you can log or put a breakpoint to verify
                @Override public void onDestroy(){
                    super.onDestroy();
                }
            };
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.fragManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(f, "getusername");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param mEmail
     *            the mEmail to set
     */
    private void set_Email(String mEmail) {
        this.mEmail = mEmail;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmail)) {
            // TODO notify caller email is ready;
            // activity.onEmailReady(mEmail);
        }
        //we are done with the "getusername" fragment
        Fragment f = fragManager.findFragmentByTag("getusername");
        if (f!=null) {
            fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you are passing an activity in the constructor, the op wants to do it w/o activity

Comment: just using the activity to get the fragment manager.  Nothing special magic happens with it.  I actually called this code from a fragment and cast to activity before calling.  Havving a class that took fragment as input I couldn't call it from an activity so it wouldn't be reusable. It works otherwise when you just call getActivityForResult from a fragment the result would come back to the main activity.  Maybe its fixed we are at what version N now.  Maybe use this method and it helps you out.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

U should pass context as Activity,then u will get solution.
try this below code.it will work

In non Activity class

```
public class nonActivity {

public static void method(Activity activity)
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);
     activity. startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
 }
}
```

In SecondActivity

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 intent.putExtra("data", "data");   //here u can pass data to previous activity
 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
 finish();
```

In firstActivity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String status = data.getStringExtra("data");
            //Do what u want with data
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("=====Exception=====" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the result back from the activity to your normal class, supposed it is a class with a custom adapter within it.

1. you cannot use startActivityForResult because you are not in an activity
2. what I did is that i launched the activity from the class with an intent. Then I calculated or did what I have to. From this activity I send the information to the main class supposed with a method MainActivity.the_method() and in the main activity I changed the custom adapter o did what I have to using the adapter object and calling adapter.getItem(position)

Hope this can give you an idea