# Call registerActivityForResult() from non-activity class

Tags: java, android

So, I want the user to pick an image from the gallery. The user gets the option to do so in multiple activities of app. I don't want to write the code for handling permissions and returning the file uri multiple times and was thinking of putting it all in one class. What would be an appropriate way of doing this? I was thinking of creating a Util class but a normal class doesn't provide me with methods like registerActivityForResult(). How can I do this? And, is there a better way of going about doing this?

Comment: Check  this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266225/how-to-call-startactivityforresult-from-a-non-activity-class-to-get-the-resuts/26223999

Comment: The Activity Result APIs [specifically cover this use case](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#separate). Did you read the docs?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks. My bad, I hadn't read the docs completely.

Comment: @AndroidGeek Thanks for the comment. I can't call registerActivityForResult() using an activity object so that wouldn't work, but the comment by ianhanniballake does seem to solve the problem.